# Copy-Item and exclude folders

Tags: powershell

I need to copy all of my `c:\inetpub` directory to a new location but exclude the following folders and their subfolders:

```
c:\inetpub\custerr
c:\inetpub\history
c:\inetpub\logs
c:\inetpub\temp
c:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

So far I am doing this:

```
# Directory name is created with a format string
$dirName = "\\servername\folder1 _ {0}\inetpub" -f (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss")
$dirName # Check the output

# Create dir if needed
if(-not (test-path $dirName)) {
    md $dirName | out-null
} else {
    write-host "$dirName already exists!"
}

#Copy Backup File to Dir
Copy-Item "\\servername\c$\inetpub\*" $dirName -recurse
```

Comment: Eh?  Is it really that hard to decipher what the text says?

Comment: I'm the only one thinking now is better? :)

Comment: Much better!  I despise posting on this site it's always given me problems with formatting!

Comment: Years later and there still does not exist an easy way to copy a folder structure with Powershell while excluding folders that match a filter within the tree. None of the answers on this page do that. The simplest way still seems to be to just use the standard -Exclude param, then go back and recursively delete all of the subfolders matching your exclusion list that -Exclude didn't catch because they're not at the root.

Answer (score 16):

This is a simple example of something you could do. Build an array of the parent folders that you want to exclude. Since you are accessing them via UNC paths we cannot really use the c:\ path (We can get around this but what I am about to show should be good enough.).

Then use `Get-ChildItem` to get all the folders in the inetpub directory. Filter out the exclusions using `-notin` and pass the rest to `Copy-Item`

```psh
$excludes = "custerr","history","logs","temp","wwwroot"
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\test" -Directory | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $excludes} | 
    Copy-Item -Destination $dirName -Recurse -Force
```

You need at least PowerShell 3.0 for this to work.

Comment: I've got an error, my PS major version is 3.
copy-Item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:15 char:93
+ ... n $excludes} | Copy-Item $dirName -recurse
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Webservices:PSObject) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: Not sure why I didn't fix this before. I had ommitted the parameter name `-Destination`. Without it the binding was messed up. It is fix now if it matters. @MJJM

Comment: Warning: If `$dirName` does not yet exist, it will be created, **but** the first subdirectory from the source won't be copied. Instead, its contents will be copied directly to `$dirName`, eliminating one level of depth. As this creates `$dirName`, the second subdirectory will be copied as intended.

Comment: @MSalters which is why I pretty much rely on robocopy now and days.

Comment: In my case if $dirName does not exist, it creates it as a file instead of directory. I had to create it before.
Very bad design in copying issues with powershell... agree with @Matt

Answer (score 14):

Oh, the answer was SO simple, but it seems we are all PowerShell noobs.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outDir # directory must exist
Copy-Item $inDir\* $outDir -Exclude @("node_modules",".yarn") -Recurse
```

It's the `\*` that makes it work.

PowerShell is awesome, but...

Comment: This should be the top answer. All other answers were producing weird results (moving SOME of the files from subdir to root etc) but this one worked perfectly.

Comment: Only works on folder exclusions at the root, not within subdirectories

Answer (score 9):

```
Copy-Item -Path (Get-Item -Path "$path\*" -Exclude ('Folder1', 'File.cmd', 'File.exe', 'Folder2')).FullName -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force
```

Replace:

`$path` by your source folder

`('Folder1', 'File.cmd', 'File.exe', 'Folder2')` by your specific files/folder to exclude

`$destination` by your destination folder

Comment: This looks great! Clean and simple. However, the excludes didnt seem to apply to the subfolders.

Comment: The gold answer! I wasted a huge time on using -Include parameter on Copy-Item itself but I wondered why not working at all. using -Include on Get-Item solved! Perfect!

Comment: This only works if Folder1 is in $path, it doesn't work with $path\sub1\sub2\Folder1

Answer (score 6):

I wrote this for daily use and packaged it in the script module, it maintains all the directory structure and supports wildcards:

```
function Copy-Folder {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$FromPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$ToPath,

        [string[]] $Exclude
    )

    if (Test-Path $FromPath -PathType Container) {
        New-Item $ToPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        Get-ChildItem $FromPath -Force | ForEach-Object {
            # avoid the nested pipeline variable
            $item = $_
            $target_path = Join-Path $ToPath $item.Name
            if (($Exclude | ForEach-Object { $item.Name -like $_ }) -notcontains $true) {
                if (Test-Path $target_path) { Remove-Item $target_path -Recurse -Force }
                Copy-Item $item.FullName $target_path
                Copy-Folder -FromPath $item.FullName $target_path $Exclude
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just call the `Copy-Folder -FromPath inetpub -ToPath new-inetpub -Exclude custerr,history,logs,temp,wwwroot`

The `-FromPath` and `-ToPath` can be omitted,

`Copy-Folder inetpub new-inetpub -Exclude custerr,history,logs,temp,wwwroot`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
  ?{$_.fullname -notmatch '\\old\\'}
```

after you get a hold of all your folders to filter them down.

This example would exclude anything containing "old" in the name. You can do this for directory you wish to exclude.

A full example:

```
C:\Example*" -include "*.txt -Recurse |
  ?{$_.fullname -notmatch '\\old\\'}|
    % {Copy-Item $_.fullname "C:\Destination\"}
```

For multiple excludes you can use `-And` :

```
C:\Example*" -include "*.txt -Recurse |
  ?{$_.fullname -notmatch '\\old\\' -And $_.fullname -notmatch '\\old2\\'}|
    % {Copy-Item $_.fullname "C:\Destination\"}
```

Comment: What if one of the wanted sub folders contained that name? Also you should show how you would account for the multiple folders the OP is looking for.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if it's worth just running the copy and then a separate delete command after to delete \\server\foldername\logs as it seems quite a task to do something that I thought would be relatively easy