# Copy-Item Exclude one dir

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to copy the content of a Folder and exclude "Cookies".

I have tried some of the provided solutions to similar questions but they didn't work for me.

```
$excludes = "Cookies"
New-Item -Path $newdir -Type Directory -Name "AppData"
Copy-Item -Path (Get-Item -Path $path"\AppData\*" -Exclude ($excludes)).FullName -Destination $newdir"\AppData" -Recurse -Force
```

I want to only copy the content of the directory, excluding 1 folder.

I'm using PowerShell V5.1

Comment: on my win7ps5.1 setup, the `-Exclude` and `-Include` parameters operate ONLY on the `.Name` part of a file object. that means the dir name will never be excluded/included since that is in the `.DirectoryName` portion of the file object. you need to use `Where-Object` to filter out dir objects. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for daily use and packaged it in the script module, it maintains all the directory structure and supports wildcards:

```
function Copy-Folder {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$FromPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$ToPath,

        [string[]] $Exclude
    )

    if (Test-Path $FromPath -PathType Container) {
        New-Item $ToPath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        Get-ChildItem $FromPath -Force | ForEach-Object {
            # avoid the nested pipeline variable
            $item = $_
            $target_path = Join-Path $ToPath $item.Name
            if (($Exclude | ForEach-Object { $item.Name -like $_ }) -notcontains $true) {
                if (Test-Path $target_path) { Remove-Item $target_path -Recurse -Force }
                Copy-Item $item.FullName $target_path
                Copy-Folder -FromPath $item.FullName $target_path $Exclude
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just call the `Copy-Folder -FromPath 'fromDir' -ToPath 'destDir' -Exclude Cookies`

The `-FromPath` and `-ToPath` can be omitted,

`Copy-Folder fromDir destDir -Exclude Cookies`

Answer (score 0):

This code is invalid `Get-Item -Path $path"\AppData\*"`, PowerShell can't concatenate the variable and the string. Change the code to:

```
$excludes = "Cookies"
New-Item -Path $newdir -Type Directory -Name "AppData"

# Join the path correctly
$joinedPath = Join-Path $path "AppData\*"
Copy-Item -Path (Get-Item -Path $joinedPath -Exclude ($excludes) -Directory).FullName -Destination $newdir"\AppData" -Recurse -Force
```

For info only: Be aware that the `-Exclude` switch only works when a wildcard is included in the path (which is done correctly in the question). [Source](http://$excludes%20=%20%22Cookies%22%20New-Item%20-Path%20$newdir%20-Type%20Directory%20-Name%20%22AppData%22%20%20#%20Join%20the%20path%20correctly%20$joinedPath%20=%20Join-Path%20$path%20%22AppData%5C*%22%20Copy-Item%20-Path%20(Get-Item%20-Path%20$joinedPath%20-Exclude%20($excludes)).FullName%20-Destination%20$newdir%22%5CAppData%22%20-Recurse%20-Force):

> -Exclude
>
> Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet excludes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcard characters are permitted. The Exclude parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it keeps being copied :C

Comment: is this becuase "Cookies" is a subdir? Its in roaming\Microsoft\Cookies.

Comment: Try adding the `-Directory` switch at `Get-ChildItem`, otherwise, the cmdlet will return the files inside the excluded directory.

Comment: I have tried this 
   
   Get-ChildItem $joinedPath -Directory | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin        $excludes} | Copy-Item -Destination $newdir"\AppData\Roaming\" -Recurse -      Force

Sry idk how do i format this to code :S PS. it didnt work, i still copies the directory :C

Comment: Okay, I'v given up on this and im using robocopy now with the /XD Parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
$destName = "C:\Test Folder"
$target = "Folder"
$exclude = "Bad Folder"

Get-ChildItem $target | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -notin $exclude} | Copy-Item -Destination $destName -Recurse -Force
```

This should work. You can set exclude to be multiple names if you want to exclude more than one folder or file. If you only want files, `-Directory` would need to be added to `Get-ChildItem`. [Copy-Item and exclude folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098220/copy-item-and-exclude-folders) I based myself off this previous answer