# Powershell, copying a folder to another dir. but not some folders in it

Tags: powershell

I'm copying a folder with its content to another dir. renaming it:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\docs1\article-title-master" -Destination "C:\docs2\articles\new-article-title" -Recurse -Force
```

Inside the folder -Path `article-title-master`there are 3 folders and in each of them there is a folder named `master`.
I'd like all folders named `master` (and and their content) from -Path not to be copied to the `new-article-title` folder at -Destination.
Is it possible to do it with a single command? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy-Item and exclude folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098220/copy-item-and-exclude-folders)

Comment: the excludes didnt seem to apply to the subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Robocopy. It worked for my test.

```
Robocopy "C:\docs1\article-title-master" "C:\docs2\articles\new-article-title" /MIR /xd "*master*"
```

**Caution!**

- /MIR will override the destination folder completely (so it can delete files as well).
- /xd Excludes directories that match the specified names and paths.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy